# Eigenfunctions of Hamiltonian in 'natural units'

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Let $H=0.5(p^2+q^2)$ be the Hamiltonian in natural units. Let $f_{n}$ be the eigenfunctions of H. Show that $\langle f_{n},f_{m}\rangle=1$ if n=m, and equal to 0 otherwise. Do this by using the creation\annihaltor operators: $a_{+}$ , $a_{-}$

we  have that $f_{n}=\frac{a_{+}^{n}}{(n!)^{0.5}}f_{0}$ so

$\langle f_{n},f_{m}\rangle=\frac{\langle f_{0},a_{-}^n(a_{+})^mf_{0}\rangle}{(n!m!)^{0.5}}$

$a_{-}f_{0}=0$ so $[a_{-}^n,a_{+}^m]=a_{-}^na_{+}^m$ and

$[a_{-},a_{+}^m] =ma_{+}^{m+1}$.

How does $[a_{-},a_{+}^m]$ relate to $[a_{-}^n,a_{+}^m]$? When I know this can I consider cases n>m, n

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

\begin{align*}
[a_-^n,a_+^m]=a_-a_-^{n-1}a_+^m-a_+^ma_-^{n-1}a_-&=a_-[a_-^{n-1},a_+^{m}]a_-\\
&=\cdots\\
&=a_-^{n-1}[a_-,a_+^{m}]a_-^{n-1}
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you help me complete the question as I'm now not sure how to consider the cases n>m, n<m , n=m?

Comment: @user108605: $\langle f_n,g_m \rangle= \overline{ \langle g_m,f_n \rangle}$, so if you consider one case such as $n>m$, then $n<m$ follows.You also need to know what $a_+f_n$ and $a_-f_n$ give in terms of $f_{n+1}$ and $f_{n-1}$ respectively.

Comment: @Alex R what happens to your equation if you apply it to the vacuum?

Comment: My literature says that if n<m , then we have a factor times $a_{+}^{m-n}$ Can you explain how they know this?